# how to attach a ActivityScenario in robolectric so my fragment will have an activity contex?

Tags: android, unit-testing, fragment

I have a fragment under test.

I want it to have an activity context so it would call in its ctor:

```
getActivity().getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.bla_bla);
```

How can i attach it to an activity context in my unit-test?

In my fragment I need to call `getResources()`, but when i create the new fragment its context is null.

```
  @Rule
  public ActivityScenarioRule<AppCompatActivity> activityScenarioRule =
      new ActivityScenarioRule<>(AppCompatActivity.class);


  @Test
  @Config(qualifiers = "sw600dp")
  public void largeScreenDeviceUsesPopup() {
    accountMenuManager = FakeAccountMenuManager.create(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());
    //not working startFragment(standaloneAccountMenuDialogFragment);
    standaloneAccountMenuDialogFragment = StandaloneAccountMenuDialogFragment.create(View.NO_ID);
    standaloneAccountMenuDialogFragment.onCreate(null);

...
  }
```

what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do it by using the activity scenario to add the fragment to the activity

```
private var activityScenario: ActivityScenario<MockFragmentActivity>
activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
activityScenario.onActivity {
            it.addFragmentToActivity(manualFragment,0)
        }
```

MockFragmentActivity is an Activity used only in tests which acts as a container.

Now i can control the lifecycle of activity with

```
 activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.X)
```

Please note that addFragmentToActivity is an extension function

```
internal fun AppCompatActivity.addFragmentToActivity(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int, tag: String? = null) {
    supportFragmentManager.transact {
        add(frameId, fragment, tag)
    }
}

private inline fun FragmentManager.transact(action: FragmentTransaction.() -> Unit) {
    beginTransaction().apply {
        action()
    }.commit()
}
```